Update my data in shiny using refresh button
I am trying to add a data refresh button to my shiny app so once I've inserted a new row into my sql table that will then appear in my data without fully restarting the app. Probably also worth noting that I'm new to shiny this week so sort of self learning as I go.
So the scenario is i have my data, i then use the textbox to add to my data in my shiny, i now click the refresh button i have created but no new data appears.
#global
myMap = #grab data from sql
theCol = sort(unique(myMap$col))

#ui
actionButton(inputId = "refreshData",
                     label = "Refresh Data")

#server
observeEvent(input$refreshData, { 
theCol = reactive({
  myMap = #grab data from sql
  theCol= sort(unique(myMap$col))
})

})
I don't think this is working correctly as the server is not set up very well, so when I click Refresh data nothing new appears like its still using the table from startup. From a search online reactiveVal() seems to be what i'm looking for here but I'm not sure how to use it.

Don't put a reactive() inside an observeEvent() - you can just add input$refreshData inside the reactive (just on the first line by itself) and it will be rerun whenever the button is clicked. Also, if you have more queries, please refactor the MRE to a functional shiny app that we can run.

Just putting together what was said in the comment.
Putting input$refreshData inside the reactive will take dependency on it even thought it's value (incremental int each time you click the button) is not used anywhere in the block.
Now theCol has become a reactive (basically it's a function) that you need to call with theCol().
I added an observe just to print to the console.
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # -- input button
  actionButton(inputId = "refreshData",
               label = "Refresh Data"))


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # update data
  theCol <- reactive({
    
    # -- just taking dependency on the actionButton 
    # (output value goes nowhere)
    input$refreshData
    
    # -- generates random strings
    myMap <- data.frame(col = do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, 3, TRUE), FALSE)))
    sort(unique(myMap$col))
    
  })

  observe(str(theCol()))
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

